# Content-Length on http GET causing IIS to timeout?

Tags: android, .net, iis

So we're encountering a scenario where our Android clients are receiving a redirect from the server (following a POST -- Post/Redirect/Get) and Android is removing the body for the conversion to GET but seems to be leaving the Content-Length header in the GET request. I've verified that the request isn't making it into the web application (by placing a delegating handler that fires before a controller is selected). We also verified via cURL that if the content-length is removed from the request, the request goes through just fine.

So we're trying to find a solution on either front:

a) how do we stop android from sending that header? or
b) how do we tell IIS to allow or strip out the content-length header so that the request can get through?

UPDATE:

Requested java code that makes the call, as requested...

```
OutputStream postOut = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("<<url here>>");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    final String method = "POST";
    final String data = "name=frank";
    final String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", contentType);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    connection.setRequestMethod(method);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
    connection.setReadTimeout(0);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        byte[] bits = data.getBytes();
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + bits.length);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        dumpHeaders(connection.getRequestProperties());

        postOut = connection.getOutputStream();

        if (postOut != null)
        {
            postOut.write(bits, 0, bits.length);
            postOut.flush();
            postOut.close();
            postOut = null;
        }
    } else {
        dumpHeaders(connection.getRequestProperties());
    }

    int httpStatus = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (httpStatus / 100 > 3) {
        Log.d("TEST", readResponse(connection.getErrorStream(), connection));
    } else {
        Log.d("TEST", readResponse(connection.getInputStream(), connection));
    }
    String finalUrl = connection.getURL().toExternalForm();
    Log.d("TEST", "HTTP Status: " + httpStatus + ", URL: " + finalUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (connection.getErrorStream() != null) {
        Log.d("TEST", readResponse(connection.getErrorStream(), connection));
    } else {
        Log.d("TEST", e.getMessage());
    }
}

if (connection != null) {
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: What kind of Android client is suffering from this? Android will not remove anything. And not add a content length to a get request as how would that be done?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Android makes a POST with a body and content-length to the server, the server response with 303 and a location, Android drops the body and performs a GET to the location but fails to remove the content-length which is causing the connection to hang. It appears that this only occurs in Android versions prior to KitKat but may be happening in KitKat as well (we have not verified)

Comment: Android makes a POST? Well no. I would think the app you programmed does a POST. So start showing/telling who really does the POST and how.

Comment: Did you think I was saying some random android device on the internet was making the post? Of course it was the client, but it is an Android library that is making the post.The client makes a post using the libcore HttpURLConnection class (android SDK) -- here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java#320 you can see it drops the body and copies the headers but fails to drop the content-length. This was fixed in OkHttp, but this doesn't help legacy clients.

Comment: Are you programming that Android app? Why are you talking about the client? Name your app. Show your code.

Comment: I am not the Android app developer. I am working with our client developers and they found that it is a bug in libcore which is what I linked. The problem is in libcore, I am looking for a workaround. If you want to see the code, then look at the link.

Comment: `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);`. I would remove that statement. `connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + bits.length);`. That is not needed normally. `dumpHeaders(connection.getRequestProperties());`. Please show the code for dumpHeaders() too. Why do you have such a function? Makes no sense to me. `readResponse(connection.getErrorStream(), connection)`. Please show the code for readResponse() too as I do not understand why its needs the connection parameter.

Comment: dumpHeaders just dumps information to the log. read response reads the response body to build an object. none of it has to do with anything.

Comment: @greenapps The client side code has absolutely zero to do with this issue. You can test it if you want - go to hurl.it and send a GET request to http://kamil.remotewebaccess.com:84/Home/TestGet and add a Content-Length:0 header. You'll get a 302 (hard coded return on that controller action). Now change the Content-Length to 1 or higher. It times out.

Comment: Why would i go somewhere to do a GET request? This code does a POST request isn't it? Please explain why that would make sense. After the weekend i will use your -adapted- code to do a POST to that kamil url. Meanwhile react to the things i said about your code.

Comment: Please read the original post -- it is a POST-Redirect-GET

Comment: Whatever you mean exactly with that. HttpUrlConnection would handle that. Why are you interfering? But you should start with a POST isn't it? And then it gets redirected maybe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get -- it starts with a POST and ends with a GET... I don't see what's confusing you. I explained this in the original post. HttpUrlConnection does not handle it correctly in libcore which is the link i posted at the beginning of this comment thread. I don't think you can help...